# How does the speed of sound relate to the phase velocity and the group velocity?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, acoustics, speed

Let us suppose we have a 1D atomic structure of masses $m$ attached with spring $\kappa$. Now given the following dispersion relation
$$
\omega(k) = 2\sqrt{\frac{\kappa}{m}}\Big|\sin{\left(\frac{ka}{2}\right)}\Big|.
$$
which is derived from the Tight-Biding model. How does the speed of sound relate to the phase velocidty $\frac{\omega(k)}{k}$ and the group velocity $\frac{\mathrm{d}\omega(k)}{\mathrm{d} k}$?

Comment: Speed of sound is the group velocity from dispersion relationship. The exact speed of sound is frequency dependent. I would guess that it appears to be constant in typical everyday frequency range because our typical everyday frequency range is way smaller than the typical frequency scale of the dispersion relationship in air, so things locally appear to be constant or linear or parabolic.